# Any way to reduce the noise in the right sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I'm trying to find out how to annotate a game. I can't find this in any sidebar. Its inclusion incredibly helps as a reference.

Instead, I see many links that are trying to take me off of the site! I should want to stay on this site, and it would improvably help me focus on my task if I didn't venture off into wondering what *Il Est* means, even if that knowledge does help a lot!

How can I remove this sidebar?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to avoid the Hot Network Questions, including ad-blockers and userscripts/stylesheets. They are listed [on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/295232).

For the replayer, you can just favorite [this Meta question](/q/3/7297) or bookmark [the corresponding answer](/a/175/7297) in your browser. It [has already been suggested](/q/390/7297) to add it to the Help Center, but as the Help Center is a shared feature among all Stack Exchange sites, it's unlikely to change.

If you want to dive into the world of userscripts, you can also write one which e.g. adds a special Replayer help button to the post editor.